# Получение списка классов из пространства имен

Tags: php, namespace

Есть ли способ получить список всех классов находящихся в опреденном пространстве имен?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761554/php-get-all-class-names-inside-a-particular-namespace

Comment: Да читал эту тему, слишком громоздкое решение, думал что попроще найти если такое имеется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в любом случае не уйти от перебора всех файлов, как устроено по ссылке, приведённой @Alpha.

1. PHP загружает только те файлы, которые реально используются в
   текущем потоке исполнения (и ровно в тот момент, когда они
   подключаются через include/require).
2. Пространства имен никак не
   привязаны вообще ни к чему. В самом корне может лежать скрипт с
   пространством `\my\super\name\space\`, а на десятом уровне
   вложенности скрипт, объявляющий классы в корневом namespace

Так что только парсить, sad but true.